# How to know winsock port is open or not

Tags: vb.net

I want to create an application server with winsock.
and I do not know how to determine if a port is open or not

```
    With AxWinsock1
        .LocalPort = TextBox1.Text
        .Listen()
    End With
```

Comment: Are you really using `Winsock` or the `System.Net.Sockets` provided in  .NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a good site to get you started on Socket programming with VB.NET if interested:
http://vb.net-informations.com/communications/vb.net_socket_programming.htm

To check if a port is open, you can just attempt to connect to it and if it throws a `SocketException` you can assume the port is closed.

```
Dim host As String = "localhost"
Dim port As Integer = 23112

Dim addr As IPAddress = DirectCast(Dns.GetHostAddresses(host)(0), IPAddress)

Try   

    Dim tcpList As New TcpListener(addr, port)   
    tcpList.Start()

Catch sx As SocketException
  'Catch exception - No available port
End Try
```